# Does not automatic sum

Tags: java

Why my pk will not auto ++ in my database? I want to let my ok auto +1 every time when I insert new details to the database...

```
public void generatePK(){
        try{
            rsCombineItem = stmtSearch.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CombineItem;");
            while(rsCombineItem.next()){
                this.pk = rsCombineItem.getInt(1);
            }
            this.pk+=1;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that you need to set up on the database side, and not in your code. Set the column in your database as primary key, and to auto increment! See the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfqZB.png) to see an example using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do here at all.  You talk about inserting but show a select statement; you talk about incrementing in the database but are incrementing in code; you have a method called `generatePK` which returns `void`; etc...

The short answer is that **you should get the database to handle this**.  Every half-decent database has explicit support for primary keys, which you can have auto-assigned and auto-incremented.  Simply set up the table to do this for you, and let the database choose the (after all, arbitrary) primary key as and when one is required.